# How does this let expression work?

Tags: haskell, lambda, anonymous-function, let, expression-evaluation

Given this line of Haskell code, my task was to evaluate it to its most simple form.

```
let g h k = (\x -> k (h x)) in g (+1) (\x -> x+x) 20
```

I have already been given the answer (and of course evaluated it myself in GHCI): `42`

However, I would like get a better understanding of how the evaluation actually works here. In general, I think I know how (simple) let expressions work:

Example

```
a = let y = 5 in y * 5  -- a == 25
```

This evaluates to `25` because we bind `y` to the value of `5` and `a` gets assigned to the value of `y*5` (the part after the `in`). The binding `y = 5` is only valid within the scope of the `let`.

So far, the only interpretation (which at least evaluates to 42) is the following:

```
let g h k = (\x -> k (h x)) in g (+1) (\x -> x+x) 20
```

- `g` is `(\x -> k (h x))`
- `h` is `(+1)` (the function `(\x -> x+1)`)
- `k` is `(\x -> x+x)`

  1. `20` is the input of `g` which yields `k (h 20)`
  2. `h 20` gives `20 + 1` = `21`
  3. `k (h 20)` = `k 21` = `21 + 21` = `42`

But what confuses me is the use of `g h k` after the let. What does that mean?

Comment: No, `g` is `g = \h k x -> k (h x)` the variables on the left are parameters as well.

Comment: [`g = flip (.) = (>>>)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:.). [`g h k x = k . h $ x = x & (h >>> k) = h x & k`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:-38-).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Think of a function definition. If you write:

```
g h k x = k (h x)
```

Then it is a function that takes three parameters `h`, `k` and `x` and returns `k (h x)`. This is equivalent to:

```
g h k = \x -> k (h x)
```

or:

```
g h = \k x -> k (h x)
```

or:

```
g = \h k x -> k (h x)
```

So we can transfer variables between the head of the function, and the lambda-expression in the body. In fact a Haskell compiler will rewrite it.

So with the `let` expression, we define a locally scoped function like the one defined above. Now if we call `g (+1) (\x -> x+x) 20`, then will thus call `g` with `h = (+1)`, `k = (\x -> x+x)` and `x = 20`.

So we will evaluate it as:

```
(\x -> x+x) ((+1) 20)
```

which evaluates to:

```
   (\x -> x+x) ((+1) 20)
-> ((+1) 20)+((+1) 20)
-> 21 + 21
-> 42
```

Comment: Is there maybe a term for this transfer of variables between the head of the function and the lambda expression? I would like to understand it better, if possible, by reading more about it.

Comment: @unnicolo It's just syntactic sugar. `f x = x` is desugared to `f = \x -> x`. All functions are ultimately defined by just binding names to lambda expressions, and moving the parameter from the lambda expression to the left-hand side of the binding is just a lighter-weight syntax for doing so.

Answer (score 10):

`g h k = ...` is a function definition. It means that the result of applying `g` to two arguments (named `h` and `k`) will evaluate to the `...` part. In other words it's a shortcut for `g = \h -> \k -> ...`.

So we can simplify the expression step by step as follows:

```
let g h k = (\x -> k (h x)) in g (+1) (\x -> x+x) 20
let g = \h -> \k -> (\x -> k (h x)) in g (+1) (\x -> x+x) 20
(\h -> \k -> (\x -> k (h x))) (+1) (\x -> x+x) 20
(\k -> (\x -> k ((+1) x))) (\x -> x+x) 20
(\x -> (\x -> x+x) ((+1) x)) 20
(\x -> x+x) ((+1) 20)
(\x -> x+x) 21
21 + 21
42
```